# Questions about the details of deriving Hartle-Hawking state

Tags: general-relativity, path-integral, vacuum, hawking-radiation, qft-in-curved-spacetime

I'm studying Hartman's "Black holes and Quantum Information" lesson(I'm a chinese so maybe I have some syntax error),and I'm confused about the Hartle-Hawking state. He says we start from the Euclidean cigar geometry:

$$d s^2=(1-2 M / r) d \tau^2+\frac{d r^2}{1-2 M / r}+r^2 d \Omega_2^2$$

with the imaginary-time identification$\tau \sim \tau+\beta$.(it's not my question,but I list here though)And when we near the horizon,the spacetime can be approximated as Rindler spacetime.And based on the idea of getting the Unruh effect, we can define Hartle Hawking state.What puzzles me is that Hartman says we integrate paths along the entire lower half of cigar, but isn't Rindler spacetime only approximating near Horizon?So HH state is a strictly defined state only near Horizon?

I don't see the specifics of the definition of HH state. When deriving the Unruh effect, we know that the vacuum state can be obtained by going back to infinity along Minkowski spacetime t ，and we get the thermal state by tracing off half of the region, corresponding to the rotation in terms of Rindler time. How this works in getting HH state？Do we still get it by going back in time to infinity along a certain coordinate system?

Also, how do we do reslice? After we did the reslice, we switched to the Rindler coordinate system (or even just approximate) with the "time" as $\tau$. What about the original slice method? Is HH state obtained by going back to infinity along that "time"?